# PyQt : How to create a menu in a QLineItem when I click it

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to create a menu when I click it like the button in my following code.
and have a action like 'delete' can delete the line

Can I do that in QLine?
or menu just can use in button...?

and I want to delete the Line, not clean the view.

I try this 
    class add_Line(QLineF):

```
    def __init__(self, title, parent=None):
        super().__init__(title, parent)
        menu = QMenu()
        menu.addAction = ('delete',self.deleteLater)
```

but it is not work
can someone help me?

```
import sys, os
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QDrag
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QMimeData


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.view = View(self)
        self.button = QPushButton('Clear View', self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.handleClearView)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.view)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)

    def handleClearView(self):
        self.view.scene().clear()

class add_Line(QLineF):


    def __init__(self, title, parent=None):
        super().__init__(title, parent)



class DragButton(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, title, parent=None):
        super().__init__(title, parent)
        self.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.showMenu)

    def showMenu(self):
        menu=QMenu()
        menu.addAction('connect', self.connectLine)
        menu.exec_(self.cursor().pos())

    def connectLine(self):
        view = self.parent()
        view.createLineItem()


    def mouseMoveEvent(self, e):
        if e.buttons() != Qt.LeftButton:
            return

        mimeData = QMimeData()
        drag = QDrag(self)
        drag.setMimeData(mimeData)
        drag.setHotSpot(e.pos() - self.rect().topLeft())
        dropAction = drag.exec_(Qt.MoveAction)


class View(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QGraphicsView.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setScene(QGraphicsScene(self))
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.setSceneRect(QtCore.QRectF(self.viewport().rect()))
        self.btn1=DragButton('Test1', self)
        self.btn2=DragButton('Test2', self)
        self.line = None

    def _createLineF(self):
        start = QtCore.QPointF(self.mapToScene(self.btn1.pos()))
        end = QtCore.QPointF(self.mapToScene(self.btn2.pos()))
        return add_Line(start,end)


    def createLineItem(self):
        self.line = QGraphicsLineItem(self._createLineF())
        self.scene().addItem(self.line)

    def clearScene(self):
        self.scene().clear()
        self.line = None

    def dragEnterEvent(self, e):
        e.accept()

    def dragMoveEvent(self, e):
        e.accept()

    def dropEvent(self, e):
        btn = e.source()
        position = e.pos()
        btn.move(position)
        if self.line:
            self.line.setLine(self._createLineF())
        e.setDropAction(Qt.MoveAction)
        e.accept()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.resize(640, 480)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QLineF only has the geometrical information of a line, it is not the item that is shown in the scene. The item shown is the QGraphicsLineItem, and that item does have the contextMenuEvent method, so the QMenu must be implemented there. On the other hand the QGraphicsItem use the shape to indicate in which part the mouse events are received, but by default the width of a line is small so it makes it difficult to obtain the mouse events so I made the shape a bit wide make its use simple:

```py
import sys, os
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class DragButton(QtWidgets.QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, title, parent=None):
        super().__init__(title, parent)
        self.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.showMenu)

    def showMenu(self):
        menu = QtWidgets.QMenu()
        menu.addAction("connect", self.connectLine)
        menu.exec_(self.cursor().pos())

    def connectLine(self):
        view = self.parent()
        view.createLineItem()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, e):
        if e.buttons() != QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            return

        mimeData = QtCore.QMimeData()
        drag = QtGui.QDrag(self)
        drag.setMimeData(mimeData)
        drag.setHotSpot(e.pos() - self.rect().topLeft())
        dropAction = drag.exec_(QtCore.Qt.MoveAction)


class GraphicsLineItem(QtWidgets.QGraphicsLineItem):
    def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
        menu = QtWidgets.QMenu()
        menu.addAction("Delete", self.remove)
        menu.exec_(self.cursor().pos())

    def remove(self):
        self.scene().removeItem(self)

    def shape(self):
        p = super(GraphicsLineItem, self).shape()
        stroker = QtGui.QPainterPathStroker()
        stroker.setWidth(20)
        return stroker.createStroke(p)


class View(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(View, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setScene(QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene(self))
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.setSceneRect(QtCore.QRectF(self.viewport().rect()))
        self.btn1 = DragButton("Test1", self)
        self.btn2 = DragButton("Test2", self)
        self.line = None

    def _createLineF(self):
        start = QtCore.QPointF(self.mapToScene(self.btn1.pos()))
        end = QtCore.QPointF(self.mapToScene(self.btn2.pos()))
        return QtCore.QLineF(start, end)

    def createLineItem(self):
        self.line = GraphicsLineItem(self._createLineF())
        self.scene().addItem(self.line)

    def clearScene(self):
        self.scene().clear()
        self.line = None

    def dragEnterEvent(self, e):
        e.accept()

    def dragMoveEvent(self, e):
        e.accept()

    def dropEvent(self, e):
        btn = e.source()
        position = e.pos()
        btn.move(position)
        if self.line:
            self.line.setLine(self._createLineF())
        e.setDropAction(QtCore.Qt.MoveAction)
        e.accept()


class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)
        self.view = View()
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(
            "Clear View", clicked=self.view.scene().clear
        )
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.view)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.resize(640, 480)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

You might consider creating a custom widget for your line item just as you did for DragButton.
Then you can implement a context menu relative to this line item to delete it, the same way you did for the 'connect' action for 'DragButton'.